# Xcode warnings referencing user account that developed a third party library

Tags: xcode

I'm using a third party library in my project - BugSense. I've added their framework to my project, initialized it, etc, so that everything works just fine.

However, every time I build my project I get a large number (40+) of these warning:

> warning: (i386)
>   /Users/genesis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BugSense-fsjysjxoaitvkaexnywkyiktqgrt/Build/Intermediates/BugSense-iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BugSense-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/BugSenseCrashController.o
>   unable to open object file

each referencing a different .o file, but all in /Users/genesis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BugSense-fsjysjxoaitvkaexnywkyiktqgrt/Build/Intermediates/BugSense-iOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BugSense-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/

The thing is I don't have a "genesis" account on my machine, so I suspect it's pulling that value from that library, but for the life of me can't find where.

Any help fixing / removing this warning is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it simply the case that the files have wrong CHMOD permissions, and Xcode can't open them for reading?

Comment: I believe that these messages mean that the person who created the library included some debug info that was specific to their machine. (I've accidentally done this with a project that I provide to others before.) There's nothing you can do to get rid of it other than get a newer version of the library which has fixed the issue. But the warnings are harmless. It's just saying that if the debugger stops inside one of the functions in the library, it won't be able to show you source for it.

Comment: I agree, they are harmless, it's just that there are so many of them - I hate to have to wade through them to see warnings specific to my own code. That's really the only reason I'd like to get rid of them - it's the annoyance factor :-)

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this question: Did you find any other solution than stripping the symbols from the library?

Answer (score 3):

If you set `GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = NO` on the bundle target that actually generates your framework binary & Bundle (not the Run Script target that runs LIPO), your problem should go away.

Reference: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/05/making-your-own-iphone-frameworks-in-xcode/#comment-2376