# Making my own framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios5

I am having a go at developing my own framework for iPhone projects that I do but when I am testing my framework i keep getting this warning :

```
warning: (i386) /Users/neilandrew/Desktop/iPhoneTemplate/******/build/******.build/Release-iphonesimulator/********.build/Objects-normal/i386/VRMinLength.o unable to open object file
```

I have found this link that had the same problem [Xcode warnings referencing user account that developed a third party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957519/xcode-warnings-referencing-user-account-that-developed-a-third-party-library) , but the comments just say to ignore it as its not really an issue to this person as its not there framework, but as I am making the framework how do I resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off debug symbols.  In the Build Settings tab for your target search for debug and turn off GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS for the appropriate configurations.  I like to keep them on for the debug configuration so I can debug, and remove them for the Release configuration.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to create static libraries, may help u..

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Comment: Thanks for the link but this is not what I am looking for. This is a static library I am looking for framework stuff. I does seem like a good tutorial though on how to make static libraries so I will have a go at that later.